# Zend > configuration for catching unmatched regex routes

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

i am using zend framework for my application and i have used few regex routes for routing the users to specific controllers and actions based on the options in url.

But when a url pattern is not matched, i get a 404 error like: Page Not Found.

How can i specify configuration, such that when the regex route does not match the specified urls, the control routes to a default controller and action?

FYI, i would like to route to the "index" controller and "index" action by default

Comment: Do you have this code in your bootstrap? Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->removeDefaultRoutes();

Comment: I dont have that code...

Comment: Do you have ErrorController setup in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Add the following parameter in your Front Controller in your bootstrap.

```
$front->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', true);
```

**Solution 2:**

Modify your ErrorController like the following,

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function errorAction() {
        $this->_forward('index', 'index');
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: @Xerkus can you explain why? considering the given requirement

Comment: this is bad practice. Best way here is front controller plugin

Comment: how will you detect non existing routes in front controller plugin?

Comment: I was wrong in previous comment. This is not 404 error issue, just no fallback route defined. Robin already gave correct answer.

I can detect by exception type in response object.

Comment: @Xerkus How to detect exception type in response, or no fallback route? I could not understand the catch all route mentioned by Robin.

Comment: @emaillenin Sorry, i could not try it now, as i am away from my system... i'll come back soon..

Comment: It have serious downsides. which are: 1)possibility of endless loop if exception thrown after internal forwarding. 2)there is no easy way to detect loop without registry/global/static variable 3)plugins allow you to change behavior dynamically without modifying error controller 4)forwarding from errorAction to specific error handler is ok but forwarding back to application is error prone approach 5)also this example have no error type check, so forwarding occurs on all errors which bring us back to 1 with much higher chances.

Comment: @Xerkus endless loop never happens in Zend Framework's ErrorController. Where there is an error in the ErrorController itself, it never gets displayed. And if there is an redirect to an index page with errors from ErrorController, the redirect stops right there at Error Controller

Comment: @Xerkus thanks for the discussion. I have learnt something new today. My longest ever discussion in SO :)

Comment: So is it ok to go ahead with this solution, or is there any better way to handle this ?

Comment: @dskanth Go ahead and try this

Comment: @emaillenin Thanks, it worked. However there is another hack i discovered: In bootstrap file, adding this logic also forwards the unmatched request to the default controller/action: **$front->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', true);**

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own "catch all" Route and place this in to the Router so that it runs *after* the regex one.  IIRC, the Router component loops the installed Routes (backwards?) and the first one that returns true triggers the process to exit.  Your "catch all" Route would always return true.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to configure this route?

Comment: Sorry dskanth, it's been a while since I used ZF, I can remember the overall MVC structure but not the details.  If you're running a later version, I *think* you can insert the Route by adding this in to the boostrap INI.  Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: For the moment, i added these lines in my application.ini file: **resources.router.routes.rest.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.rest.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.rest.defaults.action = "index"** Seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `ACL` to generate custom error

```
class Management_Access extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    $controller = $request->controller;
    $action = $request->action;

    if (!$acl->has($controller)) {

        $request->setControllerName('error');
        $request->setActionName('notfound');

    }
```

Modifying it might help you.